# Wordpress SSL on Booking Page

Tags: wordpress, ssl, gravity-forms-plugin

Good Day Mates,

A mate and I are setting up a Wordpress site for surfing tours. We are using Gravity forms and authroize.net. We had an ssl installed successfully but our wordpress page is still saying the connection isnt fully secure. https://offthebeatentrackadventures.com.au/booking-surf-trip/

It looks like it's pulling the menu items in http:// and not http://

We installed and configured the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/ to force SSL only on this page. Upon loading the [page it goes to HTTPS but the external items are loading http://

Is there any other way to get the SSL to work? It seems as this plugin is not doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

In `General > Settings` make sure the URL is entered as `https://`. The other solution is to do something with .htaccess

Comment: When you say URL, are you talking about the entire site URL? I just want the one page to load via SSL. Doing the entire site would be a site resource intensive.

Comment: would be a bit resource intesnive *****

Comment: Yea. Here's another resource for you on setting up SSL. It also includes setting it up for one single page http://yoast.com/wordpress-ssl-setup/